# Is there away to infer Base class type from Derived class?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am working on a feature for my `TypeScript` library and stuck with this typings problem. Please take a look at the following example:

```js
class Base { ... }

class User extends Base { ... }
class Product extends Base { ... }

class CompletelyUnrelated { ... }

function someFunction<TModel>(source: TModel, base: {what_to_type_here}) { ... };

// Desired result
someFunction(User, Base); // works
someFunction(Product, Base); // works

someFunction(CompletelyUnrelated, Base); // error
someFunction(User, Product); // error
someFunction(Product, User); // error
someFunction(User, CompletelyUnrelated); // error
```

To explain a little bit more about the desired output, I want to have `someFunction()` to expect `User` and `Base` as its arguments because `User extends Base`. Same for `Product` and `Base`. Is there (even) a way to achieve this? Is there anything that is close to what I want to achieve?

I have tried:

```js
interface Constructible<TModel> { // an interface to annotate a new-able type (arbitrary, put here for context)
   new(...args: any[]): TModel;
}

type BaseConstructible<TModel> = TModel extends infer TBase ? Constructible<TBase> : any;
```

However, that didn't work and I always get `Constructible<TModel>` as the result:

```js
type Test = BaseConstructible<User>; // returns Constructible<User>
```

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**: As @jcalz points out, `TypeScript` has a structural type system and I am also aware of this. @jcalz answer is completely truthful and correct. However, it's not quite what I am looking for (maybe it's not possible in TypeScript after all). Here's a case:

```js
function anotherFunction<TBase , TModel extends TBase>(source: Constructible<TModel>) {
   return (base: Constructible<TBase>) => {
      // function body
   }
}

anotherFunction(User)(Product); // no error
```

`TypeScript` has no idea or cannot infer `TBase` from `TModel extends TBase` at all. I'm wondering if there's a way to have `TypeScript` to infer `TBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: TypeScript's type system is [structural, not nominal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing); roughly, that means that if two types have the same *shape*, then they are the same *type*, even if these types have different *declarations*.  This is in sharp contrast with nominal typing as found in Java, C++, or C#, where `class A {}` and `class B {}` are different types simply because they have different declarations.

For example, if your example classes in TypeScript are [empty](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), then they will be considered the same as the empty interface `{}`, and the same as each other.  So it *might* be that some of the odd behavior you're seeing is that, say, `CompletelyUnrelated` is, despite the name, actually considered the *same* type as one of your other classes like `Base`.  If you want the compiler to see two classes as distinct, it does not suffice to have different class declarations; you need the two classes to have different members (or they need to have `private` or `protected` members, which gives more [nominal-like behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal)).

Here are some classes with enough properties in them so that `Base`, `User`, `Product`, and `CompletelyUnrelated` are related in exactly the way you intend:

```
class Base {
  base = "base"
}

class User extends Base {
  user = "user"
}
class Product extends Base {
  product = "product"
}

class CompletelyUnrelated {
  completelyUnrelated = "whatevz";
}
```

---

Now we can write the type signature for `someFunction()`.  I'd make this generic in two types: `T`, representing the instance type of the `base` constructor, and `U`, representing the instance type of the `source` constructor.  We want to [constrain](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `U` so that it `extends T`, and we want the `source` and `base` parameters to be constructors:

```
function someFunction<T, U extends T>(
  source: new (...args: any) => U,
  base: new (...args: any) => T
) { return null! };
```

---

Let's see if it works:

```
someFunction(User, Base); // okay
someFunction(Product, Base); // okay

someFunction(CompletelyUnrelated, Base); // error
//  -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'base' is missing in type 'CompletelyUnrelated' but required in type 'Base'

someFunction(User, Product); // error
// --------> ~~~~
//  Property 'product' is missing in type 'User' but required in type 'Product'.

someFunction(Product, User); // error
// --------> ~~~~~~~
// Property 'user' is missing in type 'Product' but required in type 'User'.

someFunction(User, CompletelyUnrelated); // error
// --------> ~~~~
// 'completelyUnrelated' is missing in type 'User' but required in type 'CompletelyUnrelated'
```

Looks good.  `someFunction()` succeeds and fails exactly where you want it to.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oCNHQLzQCJsIEDUBfVVUSGAVRICdoEAPAFwQDsATGeEinTQArkzyExCRmUo0o0AAqMA9jxHB2LDtz5wcyaMIAOq9ZokFTaje1lV5MAMIqAtsZAJOIAJ50ujAjgnDxCGMBuHl5BfgFBYCGWAO4AFgkIAG4AXgQA3BRUAGYiXJoAlipc0BBuCABiJeWVADwAKgA00HTanLwwrQB8ABTCNSKMwAgAXNBcCEnQQwB0K2CMAOYQM2BcPgCUeANd7cLE07PziytLa5vbuwe4R62oB4aB7ONVXCIgIACE0HI+VQAHpQdAACIICBlQKhQIQX7sVA1Vz1RrsCpcIYMaSdAQIPa5aDg6AqADWYB8qNqDVKWMqQ2UNk0BMQxNJEMp1KoaIxDOxQxc7k83ligWCCB47JInLJ0lUjDBEOgAFoNZq1UcAH56-UGw0GoxklnGaTsHzQADkZ2t0DKMFcjthXHWDqqlvNNpFUXF-kl6R49swIi0gQAjiI4dKPdAvUhrYTrXy6ZihXjGJ0WeZ2PKIYqVMqyVqtbr9SqMGaLVbrdZc-bHdBnVAym64wmbZmQ2HoJHo-COz5vdac7ZrUtU+j6U0cWO2V0mPmWIwlZXS5ry4bK9XGJabVJGI2nS62+62-Hh4n5+we+GEFGY6EL53rd3J7Tp+mmZnOr6xTEAbxCEy6FsWEIbhqW46juqjmnutYRKK0S+EBUrBg6J6tu2L5Xl2TB3n2D4DrGuEjv+KESsB0oplQVBAA)

---

UPDATE:

If you want to break `someFunction()` apart into a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) version called `anotherFunction()` then you will need to do some more type juggling to get this to happen.  The main problem is that the compiler will want `anotherFunction(SomeCtor)`'s return value to be a definite type, so you need to express that type as something that only allows a *supertype* of the class instance type corresponding to `SomeCtor`.

Conceptually you'd want the type to look like `<U>(source: new (...args: any)=>U) => <T super U>(base: new (...args: any)=>T) => void`, where `T super U` is hypothetical syntax representing a *lower bound* [generic constraint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) instead of the *upper bound* represented by `T extends U`.  So `T super U` and `U extends T` should mean the same thing.

Unfortunately there's no `T super U` lower bound constraint in TypeScript.  [See microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) for a relevant feature request.  You can sort of get this behavior using conditional types.  Instead of `T super U` you can write `T extends ([U] extends [T] ? unknown : never)>`: this ends up performing a `U extends T` check (`[U] extends [T]` turns off [distributing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over a union in `U`) and if it succeeds becomes `T extends unknown` which is always true, and it if fails becomes `T extends never` which is essentially always false.  So, like this:

```
function anotherFunction<U>(source: new (...args: any) => U) {
  return <T extends ([U] extends [T] ? unknown : never)>(base: new (...args: any) => T) => {
  }
}
```

Let's see if it works:

```
anotherFunction(User)(Base); // okay
anotherFunction(Product)(Base); // okay
anotherFunction(Base)(Product); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~
// Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'never'
anotherFunction(CompletelyUnrelated)(Base); // error!
// --------------------------------> ~~~~
// Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'never'
anotherFunction(User)(Product); // error!
anotherFunction(Product)(User); // error!
anotherFunction(User)(CompletelyUnrelated); // error!
```

That's exactly what you want, except maybe the error is weird: "`Base` is not assignable to `never`", while true, doesn't help in the way "`CompletelyUnrelated` is not assignable to `Base`" does.  So there's still a bit of a limitation here.

Okay, hope that helps again.  Good luck.

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oCNHQLzQCJsIEDUBfVVUSGAVRICdoEAPAFwQDsATGeEinTQArkzyExCRmUo0o0AAqMA9jxHB2LDtz5wcaDAAdV6zRIIm1G9rKryYAYRUBbIyAScQATzpdGCOCcPEIYwK7unoG+-oFgwRYA7gAW8QgAbgBeBADcFFQAZiJcmgCWKlzQEK4IAGLFZRUAPAAqADTQdNqcvDAtAHwAFMLVIozACABc0FwIidCDAHTLYIwA5hDTYFzeAJR4-Z1twsRTM3MLy4urG1s7+7iHLaj7yNAB7GOVXCIgIACE0HIeVQAHpQdAACIICClAIhAIQX7sVDVFx1BrscpcQYMaQdAQIXY5aDg6AqADWYG80FRNXqJSxFUGymsmgJiGJpIhlOpVDRGMZ2MGzjcHi8MQCQQQPA5JC5ZOkqkYYIh0AAtJqterDgA-fUGw1Gw20smsozSdg0gDkp2t0FKMBcjthXDWDsqVot0GtosiEr8UrSPHtmBEWgCAEcRHCZR7oF6kNbCdb+fTMcK8YwOqyzOwFRClSoVWTtdq9QbVRhzZabVY8-bHdBnVBSm744mfVnQ+H3gho7GQm2E95vdbczZrYs0+iGY0cRP2Z0mAWWIxlVWy1qK0aqzXGFafVJGI2nS62+7h53x6ZJ1he1GY-CO6Ok93p3TZxnmVmOn7xdEgZxMEq5FiWEJbpqO66nuqgWgeNrhGKUQ+EB0ohg6Z6tu2V6vl2TA9hG-ZPnGuFjv+KGSsBMqpoU36VNsKjsMk0hzkyXBNHQQyjOMZyzPMSwrOsmzQNsewHJ0rzCB8XzQK03S6DAgwANp0AAugpvTQMpLQaQA-KIXAUlwKiJJU0yzOk0i7EMpwWRcgnXMJdziY80AtA8hyGEC+SoIxzGsfRuIroMhKrry3h+SZAWMGxwqLvmoWciSZIRVQ-ksbFQVhSyt6aKB67Fv8m6QaVOrQMaMFki0eE3my7CnjMTGia2axcGAmAeAmKgjmOlnSKmGWBUKzIUQGsTobsSXyilhaFYwxWlmVy0reVhpVjVY4pphTVaLQpRtR1XXsD1179SeUVMZlcU-iFCUFcqxVDVlI0LnliVZg9RWXTFN04p9IoRABqETcGD0mMVqBAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the structural type system that TypeScript has. Everything you said makes total sense to me. However, it's quite not what I'm really looking for (Not saying that your answer is bad/incorrect). I have updated the question. Can you please take a look and provide (if any) suggestions/guidance? Thanks again

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. https://github.com/nartc/mapper/blob/master/src/types.ts#L111 super handy :D although as you said the error message is a bit cryptic but I'd settle for it for now. Thanks again for a quick and detailed answer.